# simulate the geometry distribution in Java

Tags: java, random, probability

There is an interview question as follows,
"In some place, people like girls more than boys. Once a couple have a girl, they would not consider to have a second child. On the contrary, if the first child is not a girl, they will be going to have a second child ... until they have a girl. Suppose the probability of getting a girl is 50%, what is the ratio of girls to boys."

From the geometry distribution, the ratio is 1:1.

I want simulate the ratio in Java. Here is my code,

```
package art.programming.algorithm;

import java.util.Random;

public class Probability {
private int numOfGirls = 0;
private int numOfBoys = 0;

private void random(){
    if (new Random().nextInt(1000000) >= 500000){
        numOfGirls = numOfGirls + 1;
        return;
    }
    numOfBoys = numOfBoys + 1;
    random();
}

public static void main(String... args){
    Probability p = new Probability();
    for (int j=0; j<100; j++){
        System.out.println( j + " test");
        for (int i=0; i<10000000; i++){
            p.random();
        }
        System.out.println("Boys " + p.numOfBoys);
        System.out.println("Girls " + p.numOfGirls);
        p.numOfBoys=0;
        p.numOfGirls=0;
    }
}
}
```

However, the result shows that the number of boys is alway greater than the number of girls. From these posts, [Why is random not so random?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156907/why-is-random-not-so-random) and http://engineering.mit.edu/live/news/1753-can-a-computer-generate-a-truly-random-number, I guess that the truely randomness cannot be generated without specific hardware support. As a result, the the geometry distribution cannot be simulated?
I am wondering if there is way to improve the randomness, so that the ratio of boys to girls is sometimes 10030100 : 10000000, sometimes 9999100 : 10000000.

EDIT: After putting the new Random() out the of random method, I got the expected result.

Comment: Did you mean `simulate`?

Comment: The random numbers from java can be considered truely random for 99% of applications. You do not need true random numbers for this

Comment: The `enter code here` suggests that this is homework. Is it?

Comment: @Gunslinger or sb who is new on so

Comment: @RichardTingle - I think the recursive call that happens only if you get a boy does simulate "keep trying until you get a girl".

Comment: @Don you're right, I didnt see the recursive function

Comment: When you say the number of boys is always greater;  how much greater: 1% 10% 50%

Comment: After reading the code backwards and forwards my only suggestion is to change `new Random().nextInt(1000000) < 500000` to `Math.random() < 0.5`

Comment: I get the expected behaviour. That aside, you can speed up the code *a lot* by not creating a new `Random` at each call.

Comment: @Gunslinger `Math.random()` basically creates a new Random generator every time.

Comment: @boxed__l No, only the first time. Read the code.

Comment: @Gunslinger you are right...my bad...from [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29) _"This new pseudorandom-number generator is used thereafter for all calls to this method and is used nowhere else."_

Comment: Check [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/17960/google-question-in-a-country-in-which-people-only-want-boys) question in Mathoverflow

Comment: (1) Sure looks to me like you're creating the RNG object inside the loop, and therefore not getting random numbers at all, and (2) your sample size is only 100, so you can't really draw any conclusions from that.

Comment: @AdamArold yes, it is a typo, should be simulate. Thank you!

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker The underlying question is because of the RNG provided by Java is not so random, thus the statistical quality is affected. I am wondering if there is way to improve the randomness, so that the ratio of boys to girls is sometimes 10030100 : 10000000, sometimes 9999100 : 10000000.

Comment: If you're creating the Random object inside the loop, then you're not getting the distribution of the Random object at all, you're getting the distribution of its initialization function.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Yes you are right. I am getting the expected result now.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void random(){
    if (new Random().nextInt(1000000) >= 500000){
        numOfGirls = numOfGirls + 1;
        return;
    }
    numOfBoys = numOfBoys + 1;
    random();
}
```

should be changed to (to avoid possible stack overflow...)

```
private void random(){
Random randomGen=new Random(1000000);
while(true){
    if (randomGen.nextInt() >= 500000){
        numOfGirls = numOfGirls + 1;
        return;
    }
    numOfBoys = numOfBoys + 1;
 }
}
```

Regarding Geometric distribution, there are math libraries which provide implementation of geometric distribution like [math uncommons](http://maths.uncommons.org/) and [JDistLib](http://jdistlib.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: However helpful and good design. It doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, avoid the recursive to prevent the potential stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you would sample the number of boys and girls a single couple has. You can simply repeat this process and sum up the boys and girls over a large number of couples to perform your experiment.

```
boys = 0
girls = 0

while true
   is_girl = random() < 0.5
   if (is_girl)
       girls = girls + 1
       break
   else
       boys = boys + 1
       continue
```

Here `random()` gets a random `double` uniformly distributed in the range `[0,1]`.